# Triangulations of surfaces with few vertices

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-topology

> I'm interested in *triangulations* with few vertices of a given compact and oriented surface $S$.

By triangulation, I do not mean a "*simplicial triangulation*" but  a "*decomposition of $S$ by triangles*", these being topological triangles glued by identifying edges. The only condition required is that an edge in $S$ is adjacent to two different triangles.

For instance, gluing to copies of a given euclidean triangle  along the corresponding edges gives what I consider to be a triangulation of the sphere with 3 vertices.

> **Question 1:** the study of such "triangulations" must be classical. What are good references?

More specifically, I'm interested in the following question:

> **Question 2:** for $S$ of low genus (say 0, 1 or 2) what are the different combinatorial types of such triangulations with few (say 2,3 or 4) vertices?
>   And what is the method to describe them?

Thanks in advance for any help.